# How to clean cache from a vue.js website?

Tags: vue.js, caching, vuejs2, vue-directives, vuejs-transition

So i've built a website with a vue.js. It's deployed on AWS s3 bucket that lies behind a CloudFront distribution. Recently i've found out that some users are seeing 2 week old version of the website. This is a big issue since i am updating website few times daily.

I've placed CloudFront TTL setting to 1 minute in order to try and avoid longer caching but that didn't resolve issues. I tried implementing service worked in following way which threw many exceptions and didn't work.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

I've tried disabling cache completely as well but it didn't work:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
      config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
      config.module.rule('ts').uses.delete('cache-loader');
      config.module.rule('tsx').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to represent a completely fresh content on website and not let it cache for weeks....

Comment: How do you generate the build files?